# Need hack for ie9 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Is there a hack to target IE9 only? I am facing a problem in IE9 only, other browsers are working fine. I am using `\9`, but it is effecting IE8 as well.

I don't want to use conditional comments.

Comment: Conditional comments might be your only friend here.

Comment: There is no other way ?? i dont want to use condition comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target IE9 or IE8 but not both using CSS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852681/target-ie9-or-ie8-but-not-both-using-css

Comment: no its not.Your post is for ie8 and mine is for ie9

Comment: if you do not want to use conditional comments in your project, then the only way to make it work is to learn how to code cross-browser webs without using conditional elements. I mean, there is a plenty of tricks that could resolve the problem in all browsers at once, but it will be the very confusing for you, and many hours wasted. So i suggest you, as @KyleSevenoaks mentioned already, use conditional comments

Comment: @SACHIN: not a duplicate, but the answer is right there...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this `:root #element { color:pink \0/IE9; }  /* IE9 + IE10pp4 */`

Comment: the above styling unfortunately also gets triggered in Firefox & Chrome, i found a better solution here: http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt

Answer (score 15):

I came up with a media query that does this as well. It specifies only IE9.

```
@media all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
{
    #div { color:red; }
}
```

Other ones I have worked out, including a msie 9+ media query are on my github page: https://github.com/jeffclayton/css_hack_testing - most of these I have sent to browserhacks.com for inclusion.

*2017 UPDATE*: To see it working, I created a live test page here for this and many others I worked on http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html and MIRROR: http://browserstrangeness.github.io/css_hacks.html

Please be aware it is min-width:0\0 (zero-backslash-zero) when you copy the code to your own site. Not to be confused with min-width:0 (just a single zero) which does not work to differentiate IE9 from other browsers.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. It affected only the ie9 browser and made it easy to target multiple selectors easily.I couldn't get it to compile from lesscss, but that's okay :)

Comment: Glad it could help - and you are correct, you have to use the hack as-is, not filter or compile it because it is non standard code (which is why it works). The zero-slash-zero is not allowed by many browsers or compilers.

Comment: this is coolest hack ever! works with background and doesn't affect ie10 and later. thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome! A ton of research and testing went into it, I am always glad to see my work has been helpful!

Comment: This is the true answer. It uses a media query and in my opinion its the best answer.

Comment: You are Hero, its exactly what i was looking for. It is condition for IE9 only. Great hack. @JeffClayton

Comment: @Milap glad to help, this one was after much research and testing over months of time - was really excited to see it come to be

Answer (score 5):

There is another way!

```
:root #div { background: #fff \0/IE9; }  /* IE9 */
```

Use the `:root`  psuedo selector. This works because the `@media all and (min-width:0)` part as been removed in favor of this method in IE9.

Be aware though, that this is not a safe method as it doesn't work on all selectors. The best thing to use is conditional comments, it is the safest, easiest and best way to target different versions of Internet Explorer except IE10 which has dropped the support for conditional comments.

Comment: It targets also IE10.

Answer (score 0):

In my IE9 EMULATOR none of the solutions listed worked. The only hack that properly enabled us to resize, for example, a checkbox in IE9 was:

```
/* IE9 */
:root input#my-checkbox {
    width:20px !important \ ;
    height:20px !important \ ;
    box-sizing:content-box !important \ ;
}
```

I **don't know** if this also affects IE8 or IE10 etc but we have conditionals handing those separately anyway.

Hopefully this helps someone.