# how do I use a filter: for ie8 that won't affect ie9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, sass

I have a sass mixin that allows me to define alpha backgrounds

```
@mixin background-rgba($r,$g,$b,$a) {

    $color: ie_hex($r,$g,$b,$a);
    $value: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=##{$color},endColorstr=##{$color})");

    //ie
    -ms-filter: $value;
    filter: $value;
    zoom: 1;

    background-color: transparent\9;
  // Good browsers.
    background-color: rgba($r,$g,$b,$a);
```

This works for IE 7-8, but the filter rule is being picked up by IE9. I realize I can use conditional tags in the `<head>` but that isn't really what I need. I need to be able to use this all over the place.

Comment: Aren't there 2 filter properties?  `filter` and `-ms-filter`.  The unprefixed version has been kicking around forever, but the prefixed version is newer.  This may be of use:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768161/how-do-i-reset-or-override-ie-css-filters

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to deliver a different experience for IE8 users and IE9 users?

Comment: @cimmanon The 2 filters are in the mixin.

Comment: @JonathanSampson IE9 understands rgba() natively. It doesn't need to resort to the filter, which is inferior and screws up other things like border-radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me, basically turning off the filter for IE9. I'm not happy with this solution, but it's going to have to do for now.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)" !important; /* ie9 requires quotes */
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid using conditional tags in the `<head>` to feed it IE specific CSS (as I understand your statement). There are two ideas I can think of otherwise:

### IE9 Class

Not sure if you are also opposed to [using conditional comments to set a class on the `html` or `body` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852681/target-ie9-or-ie8-but-not-both-using-css)? Or barring that, using javascript to set a similar class. Then you can preset the mixin to generate a...

```
.ie9 .yourSelectorUsingtheMixin { filter: none; ms-filter: none; }
```

... following the main entry using the `background-rgba` mixin.

### @Media Hack

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890740/are-there-any-ie9-css-hacks) notes a hack for IE9 that combines `@media` with a true hack maneuver `\0/` that would be of the form:

```
@media all and (min-width:0) {
    .yourSelectorUsingtheMixin { 
       filter: none \0/; 
       -ms-filter: none \0/;
    } 
}
```